# Why is the smallest factor of 1 considered to be $\infty$ in analytic number theory?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

In some works and textbooks, the function $P^{-}:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}\cup {\infty}$ is denoted as the function that returns the smallest prime factor of a positive integer. Furthermore, it is stated that $P^{-}(1)=\infty$ by convention.

Shouldn't $P^{-}(1) = 1$?

In the analysis of numbers free of prime factors smaller than a bound $y$, we have the function $$\Phi(x,y)=  |\{ 1\leq n \leq x: P^{-}(n)>y \}| $$
with $P^{-}(1)=\infty$, wouldn't this means that 1 is always counted by $\Phi$?

Other works where I have seen $P^{-}$ with that conventional value for [The Distribution of Prime Numbers by Dimitris KouKoulopoulos](https://dms.umontreal.ca/~koukoulo/documents/publications/primes.pdf), [Multiplivcative functions in large arithmetic progressions and applications by Fouvry and Tenenbaum](https://www.semanticscholar.org/reader/ce32fdd75a5604976302c81ebe2696e8badb1e0b)

Comment: Both definitions make no sense because neither $1$ nor $\infty$ is a prime number.

Comment: You can phrase the definition of $P^-(n)$ differently. Instead of saying "the smallest prime factor of $n$", say "The greatest element $y \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that each element of the set of prime factors of $n$ is greater than or equal to $y$". This explains $P^-(1)=\infty$

Comment: @ReinhardMeier, I understand that your new definition is equivalent to the previous one, but I still do not understand how it explains that $P^{-}(1)=\infty$. Because we do not have $n_0\in \mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ such that the set of prime factors of $1$ is greater than y since the set of prime factors is $\emptyset$ based on Peter's comment.

Comment: Each statement about all elements of an empty set is true by definition. Therefore the statement "is greater than or equal to $y$" is true for all elements of the set of prime factors of $n$. This makes $\infty$ the greatest element in $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ for which the statement holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P^{-}(1) = 1$ doesn't make sense for two reasons: first, $1$ isn't prime, and second, $P^{-}(n)$ has the property that if $n \mid m$ then $P^{(-)}(n) \ge P^{(-)}(m)$ (note that the order is reversed), and setting $P^{-}(1) = 1$ causes this property to not hold. In fact it can only hold if $P^{-}(1) = \infty$, because $P^{-}(1)$ needs to be greater than every prime.

This is an example of the funny behavior that sometimes happens with "empty operations" like the empty sum and empty product. $P^{-}(n)$ can be defined as the [infimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) over all the prime factors of $n$, so $P^{-}(1)$ is the empty infimum. In general the infimum of a subset $S$ of a [partially ordered set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set) $X$, if it exists, is its greatest lower bound; if $S$ is empty, every element is a lower bound, so the empty infimum is the *greatest* element of $X$.

Now there is no greatest prime number, so you would be justified in arguing that $P^{-}(1)$ is undefined. But in some places it may be convenient to assign it a value, and you can do that by just adjoining a greatest element; that's $\infty$.

It may seem counterintuitive that we get the greatest element here. The idea is that infimums "start at infinity and count down," in the same way that sums "start at zero" and products "start at one" which is why the empty sum and product take those values respectively.

Answer (score 0):

When $n$ is some integer, $n$ is not divisible by primes $p<x$ indicates that $P^-(n)\ge x$. For $n=1$, this $x$ can be arbitrarily large, so $P^-(1)=+\infty$.